# Property in IntelliJ: driver-class-name or driverClassName?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, jdbc

I use IntelliJ IDEA, the IntelliSense suggests the usage of assigning jdbc driver in application.properties file as

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
```

See the image when I typing

[image: driver]

But by [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715797/whats-the-driver-class-name-for-sql-server-jdbc), that is wrong. It should be

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

However a web site related to JetBrains seems indicate that using `driver-class-name` might be correct.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-202820?_ga=2.207495315.1822682194.1613252382-718343134.1609267918

So I am confused. Which one is right? Is it a bug of IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot supports both formats for properties, and they can be used interchangeably for properties defined by property binding (`@ConfigurationProperties` beans).

See also [Relaxed Binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding) in the [Spring Boot Features documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html):

> Spring Boot uses some relaxed rules for binding `Environment`
> properties to `@ConfigurationProperties` beans, so there does not need
> to be an exact match between the `Environment` property name and the
> bean property name. Common examples where this is useful include
> dash-separated environment properties (for example, `context-path`
> binds to `contextPath`), and capitalized environment properties (for
> example, `PORT` binds to `port`).

In other words, given `spring.datasource.driverClassName` is defined through a `@ConfigurationProperties` bean, you can use both `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` and `spring.datasource.driverClassName`. The kebab-case form is the recommended form. The relaxed binding was - AFAIK - introduced in Spring Boot 2, so maybe the question you referenced was still at Spring Boot 1.x.

In any case, IntelliJ's autocomplete cannot be wrong in this case, because it uses information contained in the Spring Boot JAR files, generated by Spring Boot tools, specifically for `spring.datasource.driver-class-name`, this property name is obtained from `META-INF/additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json` in the spring-boot-autoconfigure JAR file. It is also the property listed in [Common Application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#common-application-properties-data).

The Youtrack issue you listed seems to be an unrelated problem.