# No suitable driver found for Java JDBC SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, exception

I am trying to connect to MS-SQL Server using Java and I am getting

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://test.com:1435;user=test;password=test;
```

The code I am running is:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class SQLDatabaseConnection{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://test.com:1435"
                              + "user=test;"
                              + "password=test;";
       try {
         Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl); 
       } catch (SQLException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

following are the way I tried, but no luck:

1. Adding dependency in pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>12.4.0.jre11</version>
        </dependency>
```

2. Running with .jar file as classpath:
   Commands I ran:

   ```
   javac -cp mssql-jdbc-12.4.0.jre11.jar:. SQLDatabaseConnection.java
   java -cp mssql-jdbc-12.4.0.jre11.jar:. SQLDatabaseConnection
   ```

```
link to .jar file
```

https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/releases/download/v12.4.0/mssql-jdbc-12.4.0.jre11.jar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616898/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmicrosoftsqlserver)

Comment: Yes, got this error:
```                                                                                                    class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0                                                                                                                           Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath. 
```

Comment: That is another separate issue

Comment: how can we fix it? and why it is not working with pom.xml?

Comment: You are probably adding jars that are newer than your java runtime. are you running through eclipse?

Comment: Yes, updates to version to java 11 and it is working fine.

Comment: *java -cp mssql-jdbc-12.4.0.jre11.jar:. SQLDatabaseConnection* That's an odd command line, especially since you're using Maven. It should normally be `mvn compile exec:java` in the project root

Comment: Providing the JDBC driver as an dependency in maven isn't enough. You still have to set up the driver. JDBC needs to know which class it has to use as the driver, i.e. com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver, as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715797/whats-the-driver-class-name-for-sql-server-jdbc. How you set it up depends on the kind of Java app, i.e. Java SE app or an app running on an application server or servlet container. Are you using Spring/Spring Boot? Details on this and the Java version you are using are helpful.